# How do I appropriatly stock this dungeon to make it challenging but not impossible?

Tags: encounter-design, treasure, difficulty, castles-and-crusades

I'm a new DM. I built a dungeon for my players' second set of encounters. They will need to clear it in order to gain knowledge from a Copper Dragon (a passive ally) at the end.

- We are using Castles and Crusades rule set

  - It's a 5 PC party with a LoreMaster, Viking, Crusader, Friar, and
    Chronomancer all tat lvl 1.
  - None of the party members have any magical equipment at this time.
  - They will more than likely all level to lvl 2 during this dungeon(combo of role-playing and encounters plus the first encounter they will have before reaching this dungeon).

Here is the layout of the dungeon and rewards:

Room 1
Very Small 8' wide narrow short hall that ends in a dead end

Room 2
20'x20' room
200gp, a locket worth about 1000gp, and a scroll: cure lite wounds

Room 3
Cut out of existing hallway 25'x10'deep

Room 4
very small 8'x8' (you have to go through room 5 to get to)
Treasure Chest – Rust: Bag of Tricks, 500gp, Gem that glows blue (Blue Gem - Freezing Ice - Weapon - Weapon does 2d6 ice damage on a successful hit. Further if the 2d6 damage roll is "doubles" the target is frozen solid until the beginning of your next turn. A frozen target has their Armor Class reduced by -5 and all attacks on a frozen target inflict double damage. If a frozen target is reduced to 0 HP while frozen they shatter doing 2d6 damage to everything within 5 feet of the exploding corpse.)

Room 5
10'x7' deep cut in to an existing hallway to Room 4

Room 6
25'x15' room at the end of a long hallway

Room 7
15'x 30' room at the end of a very long hallway

Room 8
15'x15' room off of the hallway to Room 6

Room 9
medium room 30'x30'
Pack in the middle of the room. Guarded by a trap. They will need to figure the disarming mechanism out in order to reach the pack. Any attempt to retrieve it otherwise will result in death. The pack contains: Scroll: Sanctuary, Scroll: Temporal Sheen, Tome - Drow Language, Ship’s Compass of Direction\1 use a day – Detect Magic or Show Direction, Scroll: Zone of Truth

Room 10
medium room 30'x30'

#### My question:

1. How can I stock this dungeon appropriately in order to make it challenging yet not impossible?
2. Is the loot I'm handing out appropriate to the skill lvl of the party?

Comment: Can you share a little bit about (a) how you designed the encounters in the dungeon, and (b) what you've tried by way of gauging their difficulty? I.e. is it that you're having trouble estimating the difficulty using your methods, or that you don't know how to even approach it?

Comment: This will most likely get closed as too opinion based as there's just too many variables we don't know.

Comment: Probably more along the lines of not sure how to approach it. I think this is a good set up but in all reality its a guess on my part. I tried to gauge the parties size and lvl and then roll up an encounter.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What would I need to add in order to make this less opinion based? I would really like help here and would like to stave off a closing of this ticket.

Comment: @EddieStuder “Check my work” questions usually don't work here, when they just boil down to asking for as much feedback and opinions as possible. The site is designed to generate best answers, and a pile of equally-valid opinion/feedback breaks the voting system, so we close questions looking for that. But, based on your prior comment, this is a different question than what you're actually struggling with anyway. Maybe just cut this down to asking how to stock a dungeon so that it's an appropriate difficulty, rather than check-my-work? (“Teach me to fish” rather than “give me a fish”?)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie awesome, thank you for the feedback. I will edit my question to be a more along the lines of stocking the dungeon I have created rather than is what I've done right.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast thank you for the edit. The structure change made it much easier to read than what I had. I did add a little more clarity to the rooms and amended my question a little.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I made the changes to make the question less opinion based. Can I get the hold removed now?